# How can I make Firestore's GeoPoint conform to Swifts Codable protocol?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make the response from firestore queries conform to swift 4 codable protocol. But I am having trouble making [GeoPoint](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/GeoPoint) conform to [Codable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) as the class is already declared in the Firestore library. Thank you for your help.

i.e.

```
struct Landmark:Codable {
let name:String
let location:GeoPoint 
}
```

Comment: See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/838

Comment: Did you ever find a solution or work-around?

Comment: @Zonker.in.Geneva Unfortunately not I have resorted to using geohashes instead

Comment: I'm looking at the GitHub link above. The code for CodableGeoPoint looks promising. Did you try that? What happened?

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your declaration as a geopoint like this :

```
struct Landmark: Codable {
    let name: String
    let location: GeoPoint
}
```

But you have to add this extension in your file to let Swift knows the structure of Firebase's geopoint.

```
import FirebaseFirestore

fileprivate protocol CodableGeoPoint: Codable {
  var latitude: Double { get }
  var longitude: Double { get }

  init(latitude: Double, longitude: Double)
}

fileprivate enum GeoPointKeys: String, CodingKey {
  case latitude
  case longitude
}

extension CodableGeoPoint {
  public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: GeoPointKeys.self)
    let latitude = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .latitude)
    let longitude = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .longitude)
    self.init(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
  }

  public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: GeoPointKeys.self)
    try container.encode(latitude, forKey: .latitude)
    try container.encode(longitude, forKey: .longitude)
  }
}

extension GeoPoint: CodableGeoPoint {}
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try with an extension?

```
extension GeoPoint: Codable {
// custom codable implementation
}
```

Basically, the extension allows you to add functions, computed property and protocol conformance to an existing class/struct

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have tried this and receive the following errors when I try to build > "Implementation of 'Decodable' cannot be automatically synthesized in an extension in a different file to the type" and "Implementation of 'Encodable' cannot be automatically synthesized in an extension in a different file to the type"

Comment: Very interested in the right way to do this, am running into the same problem